# Generator of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$.

> Prove that there is a  $\tau \in G$ such that $\tau \zeta_5=\zeta_5^2$ is a generator of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$

I belive we must consider $\mathbb{Z_5}$, but I am not sure how $\tau$ behaves and why it generates the Galois group.

I am really confused by  this question so I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

The extension is actually degree 4 and is easily seen to be Galois. You just must show that $\tau$ has order 4, which by Lagrange really just amounts to showing that it has order greater than 2 and it will generate the whole group. So see what $\tau^2$ does on your generator and observe it is not the identity and the claim will follow.

Comment: Right...whoops!

Comment: Thanks. Why is the degree of the extension equal to $4$ though, I don't understand that

Comment: Do you know the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$?  Alternatively, do you know an easy polynomial containing $\zeta_5$ and can you factor the easy root out of it?